# Node js promise in a method

Tags: node.js, promise

I am new to asynch programming and I cannot understand Promises. I am trying to use a reverse geocoding library where lat/long is sent to Google Maps and a json detailing the location is returned.

```
class Geolocator
{
    constructor()
    {
        let options = {
            provider: 'google',
            httpAdapter: 'https',
            apiKey: mapsKey,
            formatter: null
        };

        this._geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
    }

    getLocationId(lat, lon)
    {
        this._geocoder.reverse({lat: lat, lon: lon})
            .then(function(res) {
                return this._parse(null, res);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                return this._parse(err, null);
            });
    }

    _parse(err, res)
    {
        if (err || !res)
            throw new Error(err);
        return res;
    }
```

When I call `geolocator.getLocationId` I get `undefined`. I am guessing that the method call exits and returns `undefined`. What is the best way to encapsulate the promise?

Comment: `getLocationId` returns undefined because you're not returning anything. If you want to return the result of the call you're making, put a `return` in front of it.

Comment: @smarx I tried that, it returns a Promise object. Not the response.

Comment: Well it can't return the response... the response doesn't exist yet. You'll need to call `.then` on the Promise and pass in a function to get called with the response.

Comment: @smarx If you don't mind, can you put some code and I will accept your answer.

Comment: What don't you understand about promises? What parts specifically?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli So from what I gather, inside the promise in getLocationId, the 'then' is simply being set with an anonymous method.  Later when I return the promise, I pass in a function to that 'then' whose parameter is the return value of the anonymous function I set before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @smarx said, you would return the `Promise` at `getLocationId()` and execute `then` branch:

```
class Geolocator {
  // ...

  /* returns a promise with 1 argument */
  getLocationId(lat, lon) {
   return this._geocoder.reverse({ lat, lon })
  }
}


// calling from outside
geolocator
  .getLocationId(lat, lon)
  .then((res) => {
     // whatever
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // error
  })
```